# driver for Atheros AR5B22 wifi card

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

My Vizio ct14 has an Atheros AR5B22 wifi card.  It was found by, and worked under the 'Try Ubuntu before loading it' on Ubuntu 14.04.3.  It would not work on Ubuntu 15.1 'Try Ubuntu before loading it' or when I installed 15.1 on the hard drive.

Is there a driver that will let me get Ubuntu communicating on the net?  I am downloading drivers onn windows 7 laptop onto usb thumb drive, then will try to transfer them to the ubuntu machine.  Can that work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6621] Kernel driver in use: ath9k 0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes

Comment: ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: After reading another question on a Dell with the same problem, I looked for a function key for WiFi.  Sure enough, on this Vizio it is Fn+F3.  When I hit it >PooF!< WiFi turned on.  I never even knew it existed after running Win 7 for 3 years.    Thanks to David Foerster and Pilot6 for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

Comment: What this command is supposed to do?

Comment: sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package firmware-atheros